# Node.js child_process exec command scope

Tags: node.js, macos, shell, exec

I have this string I need to execute on MacOS shell: `solana --help`
It runs fine as expected in the macOS terminal, even if I cd into my project directory.

The said application is on my global PATH too.

I have the following code opened in my vscode project:

```js
const util = require('util');
const exec = util.promisify(require('child_process').exec);

(async () => {
    const { stdout, stderr } = await exec('solana --help');
    console.log('stdout:', stdout);
    console.log('stderr:', stderr);
})();
```

Instead of showing expected output, the program errors out and shows the following error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fseXV.png

Comment: There's no such thing as a "global `PATH`". Each process has its own environment variables (including `PATH`), which is initially a copy of its parent process' environment. You may have some additions to `PATH` in your shell init files, but those don't affect any process that isn't run by a shell that read those files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to type `whereis solana` in the command line to find the full path to that executable, then replace that in your code, i.e:

```
 const { stdout, stderr } = await exec('full_path_to_solana --help');
```

Then show us the result.